# How to parse the <style> element's contents using beautifulsoup or any css parser tools?

Tags: python, css, beautifulsoup, styles

I have the following sample page and I would like to parse the contents of the style element:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    body {
        background-color: lightblue;
    }
    h1 {
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
    }
    p {
        font-family: verdana;
        font-size: 20 px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body id="body0">
    <h1>My First CSS Example</h1>
    <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I was able to get the contents of the `<style>` element as a binary string but not as a collection of style properties. Here's how I got the binary string:

```
>>> with open('csstestpage1.html', 'r') as fp:
...     contents = fp.read()
...     soup = BeautifulSoup(contents, 'html.parser')
... 
>>> soup.style
<style>
    body {
        background-color: lightblue;
    }
    h1 {
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
    }
    p {
        font-family: verdana;
        font-size: 20 px;
    }
</style>
>>> soup.style.text
'\n    body {\n        background-color: lightblue;\n    }\n    h1 {\n        color: white;\n        text-align: center;\n    }\n    p {\n        font-family: verdana;\n        font-size: 20 px;\n    }\n'
```

Does anyone know how to parse the contents and get a collection of style properties and their values?

Comment: check [`tinycss`](https://tinycss.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) ;)